# How to spin up an Azure VM with a cheap (non geo-redundant) system disk?

Tags: azure, scripting, disk, azure-cloud-services, azure-xplat-cli

I use the azure xplat command line tools and some bash scripts to spawn worker VMs, process CPU/memory bound computing workloads on them and tear them down again.

I spawn the machines like this:

```
azure vm create --location 'West Europe' --vm-size extralarge [...] b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04-LTS-amd64-server-20140724-en-us-30GB
```

This all works OK so far. Looking at my Pay-As-You-Go subscription lists, I see quite a bit of *geo-redundant* storage used, i.e. the second most expensive storage option.

How can I tune my setup to use the cheapest blob storage option ("locally redundant" if I recall correctly) instead?

Semi-related: I also am glad for other tips on how to save money with this kind of workload, i.e. maybe creating and using a minimal Linux image (not 30gb) could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your storage account first with the settings that you want, such as geo-replication disabled.  For example, here is how you would create a storage account in East US with geo-replication disabled.

```
azure storage account create <your storage acct name> -l "East US" --disable-geoReplication
```

Then, set the storage account for your susbscription

```
azure storage account set <your storage acct name>
```

Then, create your virtual machine using azure vm create.

Answer (score 0):

azure storage account set is not required. It is used to set/update the properties of storage-account. There is no concept of setting a specific storage account as the default one for that subscription.

Here is the help for the command that explains its purpose:

```
azure storage account set -h
help:    Update a storage account
help:
help:    Usage: storage account set [options] <name>
help:
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help                       output usage information
help:      -v, --verbose                    use verbose output
help:      --json                           use json output
help:      -e, --label <label>              the storage account label
help:      -d, --description <description>  the storage account description
help:      --geoReplication                 indicates if the geo replication is enabled
help:      --disable-geoReplication         indicates if the geo replication is disabled
help:      -s, --subscription <id>          the subscription id
```

Comment: Does that mean geo-redundancy is the default if you haven't created a storage account yourself? Because after following @Rick's answer my VHDs were stored in the new, only locally redundant container, as intended.